# my picture wont come out using background url

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, get

I am a beginner in code igniter, i save the location of the picture in database. Here, i want to display it back using background url in a div. My problem is it doesn't come out, when i copy the location and paste it in browser, the picture comes out.

I am referrig in :`<div class="patient-pic" style="background-image: url([::1]/clinic/asset/uploaded_images/togoru.jpg)"></div>`

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#patientinfo">#1 Taguro <span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down pull-right"></span></a></h4>
      </div>
      <!-- panel-heading -->
      <div id="patientinfo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Check me up</button>
            </div>
            <!-- col-sm-4 -->
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="img-patient">
                <div class="patient-pic" style="background-image: url([::1]/clinic/asset/uploaded_images/togoru.jpg)"></div>
              </div>
              <!-- img-patient -->
            </div>
            <!-- col-sm-6 -->
          </div>
          <!-- row -->
        </div>
        <!-- panel-body -->
      </div>
      <!-- panel-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- panel -->
  </div>
  <!-- panel-group -->
</div>
<!-- col-sm-10 -->
</div>
<!-- queue -->

</div>
<!-- col-title -->
</div>
</div>
<!-- row -->
```

here is my css:

```
.img-patient {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
.patient-pic {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 20px auto;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: should you just add quote in the url : style="background-image: url('[::1]/clinic/asset/uploaded_images/togoru.jpg')"

Comment: please paste an example of your image url

Comment: Since you're using codeigniter, try this: `style="<?php echo base_url("clinic/asset/uploaded_images/togoru.jpg");?>`

Comment: hello guys, i got this error: 
Failed to load the given url

Answer (score 0):

I think it's wrong url. I try debug on google developer tool. It's work fine.

[image]

Comment: hello sir. i saw an error
saying : Failed to load the given URL